# TFS integration - how to set environment variables accessible from test code

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm writing a TFS / VSTS integration with our server by using extension.

I want to present extra data after the build, specifically I want to show an IFRAME and navigate to our server, to a specific URL, determined in part by a dynamically generated unique string.

I have the function that generates the string, but I need to set it as an environment variable before the tests start to run. This is important because the tests need to create that string on the server.

I searched the documentation, examples and other places, but couldn't find a complete example that sets a dynamically generated environment variable and then runs tests.

How do I do it?

Comment: Are the tests run through the following task in build?

Comment: If your question is if the tests run in the next step - that can be arranged, as the test step is coming right after the build step. If you regard a specific task, then it seems you've forgot to state the task name... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add/set an environment variable through [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) (e.g. PS: `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"`), then the following tasks can get this variable as general variable.

With Logging Commands, you also can add additional information in build summary. (`##vso[task.uploadsummary]local file path`)

You also can deploy a build result extension to display additional information. [vsts-extension-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples)

Comment: Thank you, I already came across that example. What I'm missing is how to write a task (and what type of task) that actually sets that variable, in extension code. Any references for that?

Comment: @ItaiBar-Haim Many task can do it, such as PowerShell task: `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"`; Command Line task: `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"`; NodeJS: `Console.log("##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue")`. Does the extension means build task extension? If so, the same way, just call Write-Host, Console.log etc...

Comment: When using built-in tasks like the ones you mentioned, as far as I understand, I can only pass a constant value, not something that is dynamically generated. For that I need to create a new task. Am I right?

Comment: @ItaiBar-Haim No, you can generate a string in the same task too, then set the variable value.

Comment: Based on the build info object? If so, how?

Comment: @ItaiBar-Haim What's build info object? Provide the details of build info object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157442/discussion-between-itai-bar-haim-and-starain-msft).

Comment: @ItaiBar-Haim Could you do it in a task (e.g. PowerShell)?

Comment: I started writing a task, but I can't get it to work (I see the task running, but nothing happens, and no logs are written). I've moved on for now. Thank you for your help, BTW. I'll be in touch if and when I'll need further assistance.